# Julia : generating unique random integer array

Tags: integer, julia, random

I am trying to create 10 element array of unique random integers. However I am unable to create array with unique values. Is there in Julia something like Pythons [sample function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) ?

```
numbers = zeros(Array(Int64, 10))
rand!(1:100, numbers)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a `sample` function in StatsBase:

```
using StatsBase
a = sample(1:100, 10, replace = false)
```

This will draw a sample of length 10 from 1:100 without replacement.

Comment: What if instead of a vector (_a_ in this example) you want to create a matrix (_A_), with let's say 5 columns. Is there a way to do this? Something like:  `A = sample(1:100, 10, 5, replace = false)`

Comment: I think there is some issue with sampling matrices. But you can always `sample` a vector of dimension m*n and then `reshape` it into a (m, n) matrix.

Answer (score 8):

If performance is not an issue (i.e. the sample range isn't too large, or the sample count is close to the sample range), and if you don't want to use an additional package for whatever reason, try:

`a = randperm(100)[1:10]`

Answer (score 1):

**unique(itr[, dim])**

Returns an array containing only the unique elements of the iterable itr

```
unique([rand(1:100) for r in 1:20])[1:10]
```

**Set()**

A set is a collection of elements, just like an array or dictionary, with no duplicated elements.

```
{rand(1:100) for r in 1:20}[1:10]
```

Comment: This is not guranteed to run without errors. Also it might be very improbable for certain input.